# How to handle SELECTION of RecyclerView.Adapter in Android?

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, android-recyclerview

I need to handle when an item is SELECTED in RecyclerView.Adapter. Now I have a touch listener on the view, but I need "less sensible trigger". If list is scrolled, I do not want touch to enable. But I would avoid any "clever fix". Is it any standardized solution for it, like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, in iOS in `UITableView` itself has a event handler mechanism. Anything in Android?

Not it is:

```
boardUserHolder.imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements AdapterView.OnClickListener {
public TextView mTextView;

private ViewHolder(View itemView, TextView textView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextView = textView;
}

@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try to implement `onClick` listener in the `ViewHolder` instead of
>   onTouchListener. And you can get selected position using 
>   `getAdapterPosition()` method.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
  public TextView mTextView;

  private ViewHolder(View itemView, TextView textView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextView = textView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

lets say you want to doSmt() when you click on the Image .

1- make an Interface in your Adapter class :

```
public interface myInterface = {
      void doSmt();
 };
```

2- make a global variable in your Adapter class:

```
private myInterface _myInterface ;
```

3- make a setter function for _myInterface inside your Adapter class :

```
public void setInterface(myInterface m){
   this._myInterface = m l 
}
```

4- now we have an interface with method doSmt() , to use this method when you click on your imageView , simply do this :

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        { _myInterface.doSmt(); }
```

5- if you run the code now , nothing will happen because doSmt() is empty , now , make your Activity (which use your RecyclerView inside of it) implement the interface myInterface , and you will have to implement doSmt() too and fill it with your action you want to do .

6- in your Activity , use the setter method which you create in step 3

```
myAdapter.setInterface(this);
```

now if you run the code and click on the ImageView , the code in doSmt() will run .